# Handlebar helper not executing on input change

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

```
<select name="state">
   {{#each states as |state|}}
       <option value={{state.id}} disabled={{is-selected state.id matchedFilters}}>{{state.name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

When user select an option i will add that option to matchedFilters array. Now i want the selected option to be disabled. so i wrote a helper for that.

```
export function isSelected(params) {
  let selected = params[0];
  let options = params[1];
  return options.indexOf(selected) >= 0;;
}
```

But this helper is executing only on load. i want that helper to execute every time matchedFilters change.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `matchedFilters` is not being observed by your `is-selected` helper - as you are most likely just modifying its content (pushing state ids) instead of setting the array instance to the new array.

I've create a twiddle with two working versions of `is-selected` helper. Hopefully that clears it up for you.

https://ember-twiddle.com/302ac612ba08293184a09c452ef0d8e0?openFiles=helpers.is-selected-smart.js%2C

Comment: It is being watched, but the binding is not changing, like you mention, just the contents.

Comment: right - the first implementation of the before mentioned helper in twiddle actually demonstrates that the binding is updating when you explicitly set the array. thanks for clearing it up!